# Forcing keydown event to fire (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, input

I am creating an input system (using the windows messaging system) that I would now like to unit test. A window has been created for testing but I am wondering how to fire the key (and mouse) events programatically so that I can test that the corresponding flags in the input system are being set and unset properly.

Comment: @ildjarn: That is exactly what I am looking for. If you put that as the answer, I can check mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the purpose of [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Synthesizes keystrokes, mouse motions, and button clicks.